# c++ SetWinEventHook issue with both 32 & 64 bit application

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, get-winevent

I'm trying to hook winevents like EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART and EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND with all desktop windows.
For this, I used SetWinEventHook().
Here's my sample code.

```
    BOOL DlmSetEventHook()
    {
    if (hInstance == NULL)
        return FALSE;
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    hWEventHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART, EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND, NULL, WinEventProc, NULL, NULL, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT );
    if ( hWEventHook == NULL )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
    }
```

It's portion of Installed Hook.

```
void DlmRemoveEventHook()
{
    WaitForSingleObject(hWEventHook, INFINITE);
    UnhookWinEvent(hWEventHook);
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

The above is for removing WinEvent Hook.

And this is HookProc Function.

```
void CALLBACK WinEventProc(
    HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook,
    DWORD         event,
    HWND          hwnd,
    LONG          idObject,
    LONG          idChild,
    DWORD         dwEventThread,
    DWORD         dwmsEventTime
)
{
IAccessible* pAcc = NULL;
VARIANT varChild;
HRESULT hr = AccessibleObjectFromEvent(hwnd, idObject, idChild, &pAcc, &varChild);

if ((hr == S_OK) && (pAcc != NULL))
{
    if (event == EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART)
    {
        if (!(::GetWindowLong(hPaneWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_VISIBLE))
        {
            ::ShowWindow(hPaneWnd, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
            ::UpdateWindow(hPaneWnd);
        }

    }

    if (event == EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND)
    {
        if ((::GetWindowLong(hPaneWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_VISIBLE))
        {
            ::ShowWindow(hPaneWnd, SW_HIDE);
        }
    }
    pAcc->Release();
}
}
```

The above codes are all in DLL. And I compiled DLL with x86 Debug method.
And I, of course, compiled client project with x86 Debug method.
My problem is that this hookproc listens for events which caused on only x64 bit apps.(I use Win10 x64).
It cannot listen for winevents of x86 bit apps.
I only know that 32 bit dll can only injected into 32 bit project and same thing on 64 bit dll.
But I think that it's not related to winevent hook.
What's wrong on my code? And Which things do I never know?

Comment: Not the problem but you should check event before doing any other work.

Comment: Why are you calling `AccessibleObjectFromEvent()` when you are not using the `IAccessible` for anything? And why are you passing `hWEventHook` to `WaitForSingleObject()`? An event hook is not documented as being a waitable object. And if this code is inside a DLL then it shouldnt be calling `Co(Un)Initialize()` unless this code is in a worker thread created by the DLL, otherwise let the calling app thread handle those calls instead. But why are you using a DLL at all? `SetWinEventHook()` doesn't require a DLL, unlike `SetWindowsHookEx()`

Comment: My crystal ball says that you run VS elevated.  Don't do that.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.
@Anders, what do you mean - any other work?

Comment: @Remy, AccessibleObjectFromEvent is not necessary on my code. This is my fault. And then in terms of DLL, my current project requires some other works and DLL is arbitrary. 
That's all. I'll follow your idea. - Not using WaitForSingleObject & Co(Un)Initialize().

Comment: @Hans, I use VC 2015. And I think that it's not elevated version of IDE.

Comment: After overview of In-Context & Out-Context Hook Function on msdn,
I'm wondering about marshalling.
What is marshalling of WinEvent?
Wish to read more readable description, more like with example.